# error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct card’ from type struct card *’

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Keep on getting this error in one of my functions. Not Sure why.

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type `struct card` from type `struct card *`

```
Struct card** shuffleDeck(Struct card deck[], int size)
{
 int i, j;
 struct card temp;
 struct card** dealerDeck;
 dealerDeck = malloc(size*sizeof(struct card*)*4);
 for(i=0; i<size; i++)
 {
     dealerDeck[i] = (struct card**)malloc(size*sizeof(struct card));
     j = rand()%size;
     temp = dealerDeck[i]; //ERROR ON THIS LINE
     dealerDeck[i] = dealerDeck[j];
     dealerDeck[j] = temp; //ERROR ON THIS LINE
 }
};
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You should listen to your compiler.... If your title is the error message, it is telling you exactly what is wrong -- and is probably even given you a line number where the problem occurs. You can learn a lot of C, just by listening to what your compiler is telling you -- if you only take the time to listen...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to make this `temp = dealerDeck[i];` happen `temp` should be type `struct card *temp`

```
struct card *temp  = NULL;
/* memory allocation */
temp = dealerDeck[i]; /* now its possible */
```

Also avoid casting `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that, which then led to this warning. --> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   dealerDeck[i] =(struct card**)malloc(size*sizeof(struct card));
                 ^

Comment: `dealerDeck[i] = (struct card**)malloc(size*sizeof(struct card));`--->`dealerDeck[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(struct card));`

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys.